# CanCan denies authorization when can :create is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

My CanCan implementation is denying access when I have called the can method with :create specified.  Here is my ability implementation:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # User is not logged in (Guest)
    if user.id == nil # Guest user
      can [:create, :update], Device
    else
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
       else
        can :manage, Spot, :user_id => user.id
      end
     end
   end
end
```

Basically I want non-authenticated users to be able to submit POST and PUT requests to the create and update actions of my Devices controller.  However, when I try to submit a POST request the request is denied by CanCan (I'm asked to log in).

At the top of my devices controller I simply call load_and_authorize_resouce.

Does anyone see why CanCan would be raising an AccessDenied exception on this?

Comment: Check somewhere in the relevant controller whether `can? :create, Device` is returning true for the guest user?

Comment: As it turns out my authorization was triggering because of a left over line I added a while ago and forgot about.  It's working now, sorry about that one folks.